# Flexslider caption only display on first slide

Tags: html, css, flexslider

I have implemented flexslider on a website I'm building. For some strange reason the caption only appears on the first slide.

The captions are there in the markup on the other slides, but for some reason they are not displaying how they should, like the first slide is doing so correctly.

I guess I'm incorrectly doing something with the CSS, maybe positioning somewhere?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `.flexslider .slides > li`

You might need to adjust the width/height. But this should work.